# How to retrieve combobox selection in a windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

All,

I have a simple windows form with a combobox and a 'OK' button.  After clicking the 'OK' button, I want to retrieve the selected combobox value.

The GetUserForm has 2 controls:
combobox named cmbUser, with a list of 2 values
button named btnOK

Nothing has been done to the GetUserForm class itself.  The class contains:

```
public partial class GetUserForm : Form
{
    public STAMP_GetUser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

GetUserForm f = new GetUserForm();
f.ShowDialog();
// not sure how to access the combobox selected value?
```

Do I need to initialize something in the class?  Or can I access the controls on the form using the 'f' variable above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expose the value of the ComboBox as a public property. Something like that :

```
public string SelectedUserName
{
    get { return cmbUser.Text; }
}
```

Or perhaps :

```
public int SelectedUserId
{
    get { return  (int)cmbUser.SelectedValue; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an extra (public) property on your '`GetUserForm`' class which returns the value of the selected item of the combobox that is on that form.

For example:

```
public class GetUserForm : Form
{
    public object SelectedComboValue
    {
        // I return type object here, since i do not know what you want to return
        get 
        {
           return MyComboBox.SelectedValue; 
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can do this:

```
using( GetUserForm f = new GetUserForm() )
{
     if( f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
     {
          object result = f.SelectedComboValue;

          if( result != null )
              Console.WriteLine (result);
     }
}
```

Comment: This also helped me a lot in understanding the public properties.